# Advice for ruby

Tags: code-golf, tips, ruby

How can I shorten:

```
p=gets.to_i
a=gets
b=gets.to_i
```

If my input is an integer, followed by a string, followed by an integer?

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: For the people that will say that this is off topic, if you want to argue it is, read through meta and then message me.

Answer (score 7):

### Use ARGV ($*) and mass assignment

*(disclaimer: I don't know Ruby, but this works [on TIO](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0AnUSfJVkWLq8C2QK8kPz6TK8k2CcIoKC0pVkiEUEnaBf///zf8X5JaXPLfGAA))*

```
p,a,b=$*
p=p.to_i
b=b.to_i
```

<s>28</s> 26 bytes instead of 30 (thanks to Snack for pointing out the $* trick)

Comment: ARGV can also be accessed as $* which saves two bytes

Comment: @Snack Hehe, golfing a tips answer :)

Answer (score 6):

## Use a lambda

Answers are typically allowed as lambda functions with your input/output being the parameters/return value of the lambda, so you can do this:

`->p,a,b{...}`

If you assigned this to a variable `f` then it would be called as

`f[p,a,b]`

It's generally fine to assume the types of the inputs as well, but to be safe you can mention it in your answer.

[Relevant meta post about acceptable input/output methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods)

Answer (score 6):

If you need a full program with stdin/stdout io for some reason, the shortest you can do is use the `-n` flag to shorten one call to `gets.to_i` to `eval$_`:

```
p=eval$_
a=gets
b=gets.to_i
```

The `-n` flag surrounds your code with `while gets ... end`, so the program will loop if more input is supplied than your program consumes.